# SELECT query results in "Fatal Error Out of Memory"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, out-of-memory

```
$chk = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM af_rpta_faas_land_notapproved  AS t1 ,af_rpta_faas_land_notapproved_address  AS t2 ,af_rpta_faas_land_notapproved_approval  AS t3 ,af_rpta_faas_land_notapproved_boundaries  AS t4,af_rpta_faas_land_notapproved_ownerinfo  AS t5 ,af_rpta_faas_land_notapproved_references  AS t6 ,af_rpta_faas_land_notapproved_status  AS t7 ,af_rpta_faas_land_not_approved_aprroval_files  AS t8,af_rpta_faas_land_not_approved_valuation  AS t9 WHERE t1.pin = :pin AND t1.status = :active AND t2.pin = :pin AND t2.status = :active AND t3.pin = :pin AND t3.status = :active AND t4.pin = :pin AND t4.status = :active AND t5.pin = :pin AND t5.status = :active AND t6.pin = :pin AND t6.status = :active AND t7.pin = :pin AND t7.status = :active AND t8.pin = :pin AND t8.status = :active AND t9.pin = :pin AND t9.status = :active ");
$chk->bindValue(":pin", $pin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$chk->bindParam(":active", $propertystatus, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if ($chk->execute())
    {
    echo $chk->rowCount();
    }
```

This is my select statement its is very simple. It selects data and blob from different table. But it is returns:

> **Fatal error:** Out of memory (allocated 1310720) (tried to allocate 10221840 bytes)

I've read a couple of articles that says I should increase `max_allowed_packet` but then it didn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update**

---

Changed `memory_limit=128M` to `memory_limit=256M` in `php.ini`

```
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

**to:**

```
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 32M
```

in my.ini

Comment: Why are you executing the query twice?

Comment: i think not because i am having this query inside a condition so if the condition is met it will run if not it will not run. i have a question if ever that it is the  case how can i check if the query is run more than once?

Comment: You are running it more than once. The code is saying that.`if ($chk->execute())
    {
    echo $chk->execute();
    }`

Comment: `max_packet_size` wont fix your problem. `memory_limit` will.  also it seems to me that you're simply cross joining all those tables which will result in a horrendously massive result set. you need to include some relational criteria on the joins, otherwise you're result is the total rows in each table multipled together.

Comment: my bad i edit it already it is suppose to be `rowcount`

Comment: @pala_ i also changed that one wasnt able to write it. default memory_limit is 128 right i changed it `memory_limit=256M ` still i have that error. sorry for poor update on question i will update again

Comment: @HogRider simply put. you are returning more data than you think you are. try `select count(*)` instead of `select *` and see how many rows it returns - i bet its more than you want.

Comment: i tried `select count(*) FROM ` until now the request is still pending so i am assuming that i will stuck there forever. working with Select count is same with select right?i just change `*` to `count(*)`. also i have less than 30 rows in my database so i think i should not be a problem

Comment: You have less than 30 rows **total** in all the tables this references?

Comment: im sorry i already truncate the tables let me add data again and see what will happened. @MikeFulton

Comment: @MikeFulton now i have `14580` when i echo `rowCount();` i get error how to fix this one?

Comment: i am not sure why u have that rowCount() when in my table i only have few rows with status `Active`